# get date from string php - UK date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a UK date in the format "06/Apr/2010 13:24" that I need to insert into a mysql db date field.

The PHP strtotime function can't handle this string-- has anyone got any ideas other than writing a custom function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing / with -

```
strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '06/Apr/2010 13:24'));
```

Comment: thanks webbiedave-- that's the quick and easy answer I was hoping for!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could substring on the space then explode on the "/"'s and then be able to get each piece to work with.  Seems odd that there isn't already a way to do  this...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$date = strtotime(str_replace('/',' ',$date).":00");
```